# How to configure DNS for KNative when there isn't an External IP but there is an istio-ingressgateway?

Tags: knative

The [knative docs](https://knative.dev/docs/install/install-serving-with-yaml/#configure-dns) describe the following:

> To configure DNS for Knative, take the External IP or CNAME from setting up networking, and configure it with your DNS provider as follows
>
> - If the networking layer produced an External IP address, then configure a wildcard A record for the domain:
>
>   `# Here knative.example.com is the domain suffix for your cluster`
>
>   `*.knative.example.com == A 35.233.41.212`
> - If the networking layer produced a CNAME, then configure a CNAME record for the domain:
>
>   `# Here knative.example.com is the domain suffix for your cluster`
>
>   `*.knative.example.com == CNAME a317a278525d111e89f272a164fd35fb-1510370581.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

However, my environment doesn't have an external load balancer and hence no EXTERNAL-IP:

```
$ kubectl --namespace istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway
NAME                   TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                      AGE
istio-ingressgateway   NodePort   10.110.132.172   <none>        15021:31278/TCP,80:32725/TCP,443:30557/TCP,15443:32309/TCP   8h
```

I do have an istio-ingresgateway configured:

```
$ kubectl get po -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system \
     -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.hostIP}'
10.1.0.193 10.1.0.132 10.1.0.174
```

Can I simply set up DNS as follows?

```
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.193
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.132
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.174
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `hostPort` networking here; if that's the case, then Kubernetes will map port 80 and 443 of the host's IP address to Istio's envoy pods. This week work as long as your istio-ingressgateway pods remain scheduled on the same machines (for example, if you use a daemonset and have 3 nodes in the cluster, put all three node IPs in DNS). Here are a few places where this will break down and a Kubernetes LoadBalancer service will work better:

- If one of the hosts fails, 1/N clients will try the bad IP address and may error out or have a long timeout and then retry. You'll need to take the host out of DNS to make this work.
- If you have more hosts than istio-ingressgateway pods, every time one of those pods is rescheduled (Deployment update, host kernel upgrade, etc), you'll have an outage like the above. Using a DaemonSet can avoid this if have less than 5-7 hosts, but larger sets of records may cause other problems.
- You can't use a HorizontalPodAutoscaler (HPA) to rightsize the number of istio-ingressgateway pods (see above for mismatch consequences)

If possible, you might look at [MetalLB](https://MetalLB.io/) as a lie-cost software load balancer of any of the above concern you. If none of the above are major concerns, nodePort services are a bit simpler than LoadBalancer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up DNS as follows works ok so far for me:

```
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.193
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.132
*.knative.example.com     [some TTL]   IN   A    10.1.0.174
```